# Equivalent of Javascript's parseInt in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

Can I do something similar to this in PHP? It's checking if a number is to the nearest dime.

```
parseInt(fValue * 10, 10) / 10 === fValue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rory
I think need like this

```
((int)($fValue * 10))/10 === $fValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try typecasting to int

Like this

```
(int)(fValue * 10, 10) / 10 === fValue ;
```

And only `fValue` in not valid variable in php, append `$` to it.

```
(int)($fValue * 10, 10) / 10 === $fValue ;
```

With division and comparision, you mite not get result as expected, so use `abs()` in case.

Like

```
if (abs((6.6 - 6.6)/ 6.6) < 0.00001) {
    echo '<br />Both are equal ';
}
else{
    echo '<br />Both are not equal ';
}
```

Without `abs()` it will enter `else`, with abs, it will enter `if()`